# C Multiple arrays permutations algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, permutation

I'm trying to write a program that generates permutations upon a list of words stored into several arrays. 
For example, my program asks for 2 groups of words like this :

```
words #1: abc def ghi
words #2: 123 456
```

What i'm trying to have is this output:

```
abc 123 | abc 456 | def 123 | def 456 | ghi 123 | ghi 456
```

Or:

```
123 abc | 123 def | 123 ghi | 456 abc | 456 def | 456 ghi
```

The order doesn't matter.

I'd possibly make the group of words array with a non-fixed size. Then the input would be:

```
words #1: abc def ghi
words #2: 123 456
words #3: ** --
```

And the output:

```
abc 123 ** | abc 123 -- | abc 456 ** | abc 456 -- | def 123 ** | def 123 -- | def 456 ** | def 456 -- | ghi 123 ** | ghi 123 -- | ghi 456 ** | ghi 456 --
```

I think I had to consider using a recursive function but i'm a bit confused.
Here is what I've written :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct permut_word_s {
    char *str;
} permut_word_t;

typedef struct permut_group_s {
    permut_word_t *words;
    int nb_words;
} permut_group_t;

static int split(char *str,
                 char *token,
                 permut_group_t *g) {
    permut_word_t *a = NULL;
    permut_word_t *t = NULL;
    char *p = NULL;
    int nbw = 0;
    int l = 0;

    if(!str || !token || !g) {
        return -1;
    }

    p = strtok(str, token);

    while(p != NULL) {
        if(!(t = realloc(a, (nbw + 1) * sizeof(permut_word_t)))) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(!(t[nbw].str = malloc(strlen(p) + 1))) {
            return -1;
        }
        memset(t[nbw].str, 0, strlen(p) + 1);
        if(!(strncpy(t[nbw].str, p, strlen(p)))) {
            return -1;
        }
        nbw++;
        p = strtok(NULL, token);
        a = t;
    }

    g->words = a;
    g->nb_words = nbw;

    return 0;
}

void word_free(permut_word_t *w) {
    if(!w) {
        return;
    }

    if(w->str) {
        free(w->str);
    }

    return;
}

void group_free(permut_group_t *g) {
    int i = 0;

    if(!g) {
        return;
    }

    for(; i < g->nb_words; i++) {
        if(&g->words[i]) {
            word_free(&g->words[i]);
        }
    }

    free(g->words);
    return;
}

void permut(permut_group_t *g,
            int cur,
            int len) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    if(cur == len) {
        return;
    }

    for(i = cur; i < len; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < g[cur].nb_words; j++) {
            printf("%s ", g[cur].words[j].str);
        }
        permut(g, cur + 1, len);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    permut_group_t *groups = NULL;
    int len = 0;

    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    if(!(groups = malloc(2 * sizeof(permut_group_t)))) {
        return -1;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "words #1: ");
    fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
    split(buf, " ", &groups[0]);
    len++;

    fprintf(stdout, "words #2: ");
    fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
    split(buf, " ", &groups[1]);
    len++;

    permut(&groups[0], 0, len);

    group_free(&groups[0]);
    group_free(&groups[1]);
    free(groups);

    return 0;
}
```

How can do it correctly knowing that the groups array may have a variable size?

Comment: That looks like a cartesian product, not a permutation

Comment: @EliKorvigo that is true. I guess they both fall under combinatorics, just two different applications.

Comment: I wrote it because the title was confusing. At some point people will be googling something related to permutations and might end up here only to find that it is not relevant at all. At the same time people looking for a product implementation won't be able to find your solution. It's is a matter of usefulness from the community's perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```cpp
void permut(permut_group_t *g,
            int cur,
            int len, char *result=NULL) {
    int j = 0;

    if(cur == len) {
        printf("%s\n", result);
        return;
    }

    for(j = 0; j < g[cur].nb_words; j++) {
        char nextLine[200];
        if (cur==0)
            strncpy (nextLine, g[cur].words[j].str, 200);
        else
            snprintf (nextLine, 200, "%s;%s", result, g[cur].words[j].str);

        permut(g, cur + 1, len, nextLine);
    }
}
```

The following input

```
words #1: AB CD
words #2: 11 22 33
```

produces then the following output:

```
AB;11
AB;22
AB;33
CD;11
CD;22
CD;33
```

The trick is that when collecting the results, intermediately achieved combinations have to be kept and passed to the next level. Therefore, signature of function `permut` has been extended by an (optional) parameter `char* result`, which serves as "memory" for these intermediate (or final) combinations.

The signature of the permutation function is now `permut(permut_group_t *g, int cur, int len, char *result=NULL)`; from function `main`, you can keep your call `permut(&groups[0], 0, len)` as is, because optional parameter `result` can be omitted when parameter `cur` is 0;

Note that I extended also function `split` in order to strip any trailing new lines, such that these new lines do not get copied into the results:

```
char *newLine = strrchr(str, '\n');
if (newLine)
    *newLine = '\0';
```